# Customize newcounter with chapter number

Tags: numbering, environments

I explain my problem:
I am writing a book and I am using \newcounter to number the examples.
At the moment I am creating an enviroment like this

```
\newcounter{xmpl}[chapter]
\newenvironment{example}{
     \def\FrameCommand{\colorbox{colxmplboxcolor}}%
     \MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}
     \vspace{0.2cm} \noindent \refstepcounter{xmpl} \textbf{Example  \thexmpl \\ }
}
{\vspace{0.2cm}\par\noindent%
    \ignorespacesafterend
    \endMakeFramed}
\definecolor{colxmplboxcolor}{HTML}{F8E0E0}
```

In this way newcounter will reset at any chapter, but what if I want the number of the chapter inside the number of the example?
For instance:

> Second example of chapter 4
>
> Example 4.2

Comment: Before you get too far have you checked the options from the `tcolorbox` package. It can straight up do what you are doing by hand right here, with much better interfaces.

Comment: But colorbox is for the background color, why should it be useful in numbering?

Comment: Everything you do here, including the background, counters etc can be made using `tcolorbox` via a key=value interface. See section 17 in the `tcolorbox` manual. It is a wast of time trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Otherwise just redefine `\thexmpl` (I would have sworn that `\newcounter` did that automatically)

Comment: BTW: you have some sporadic spaces in that definition, thus the header line starts with at least one space.

Comment: I've read the manual of tcolorbox. I didn't know the existance of the package. It helps a lot and is way better. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use commands from the LaTeX kernel:

```
\newcounter{xmpl}
\counterwithin{xmpl}{chapter}
```